# Use variable after common table expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried to capture a value derived from CTE (Common Table Expression) Table into a variable. For some reason it doesn't seem to work. Below is the code:

```
WITH CTE
as
(
    select 
    Case 
        when target_title like '%P1%' then 'P1'
        when target_title like '%P2%' then 'P2'
        when target_title like '%P3%' then 'P3'
        when target_title like '%P4%' then 'P4'
    End as Priority,
    flag,
        case when flag='Response' then Business_Hours_MMTR end as Response,
        case when flag = 'Resolution' then Business_Hours_MMTR end as Resolution
    from Keurig..Response_Resolution
    where [Group] like '%Network%'
and datepart(month, Measurement_Stop) =  datepart(month, Getdate())-1
and (Target_Title like '%P1%' OR Target_Title like '%P2%' OR Target_Title like '%P3%' OR Target_Title like '%P4%')
)
Declare @K4Resp numeric(5,2);
Select @K4Resp = CAST(AVG(Response) as numeric(10,2)) as K4Response from CTE where flag = 'Response' and Priority = 'P4'
group by Priority, flag
```

Comment: The first statement after a `CTE` has to be a `Select` statement. Declare your variable above your `CTE`

Comment: Random `AVG(Response)` from the result will be assigned to `@K4Resp`

Comment: You have a couple of other issues here besides the placement of your declaration. You define your variable as numeric(5,2) but in your query you cast it as numeric(10,2). You also are setting the value of a scalar variable to the results of a query that can have multiple lines.

Comment: Could you be more vague about "doesn't _seem_ to work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your declaration before the [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). Only the statement after the cte can reference the cte. In this case, that was your `declare`.

```
declare @K4Resp numeric(5, 2);
with CTE as (
  select 
      case 
        when target_title like '%P1%' then 'P1'
        when target_title like '%P2%' then 'P2'
        when target_title like '%P3%' then 'P3'
        when target_title like '%P4%' then 'P4'
      end as Priority
    , flag
    , case when flag = 'Response' then Business_Hours_MMTR end as Response
    , case when flag = 'Resolution' then Business_Hours_MMTR end as Resolution
  from Keurig..Response_Resolution
  where [Group] like '%Network%'
  and datepart(month, Measurement_Stop) = datepart(month, Getdate()) - 1
  and ( Target_Title like '%P1%'
     or Target_Title like '%P2%'
     or Target_Title like '%P3%'
     or Target_Title like '%P4%'
     )
)
select @K4Resp = CAST(AVG(Response) as numeric(5, 2))
from CTE
where flag = 'Response'
  and Priority = 'P4'
group by 
    Priority
  , flag
```

Comment: By looking at the `group by` I don't think OP will get the right value assigned to the `@K4Resp` variable

Comment: select @K4Resp = CAST(AVG(Response) as numeric(10, 2)) as K4Response: "as K4Response" has to be removed because we are assigning the selected value to a variable.

Comment: Thanks @SergioPrats. Removing "as K4Response" resolved the issue.